# Dialog Icon doesn't appear in Kotlin dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an android app made by kotlin I made a dialog in it and set Icon to this dialog but the icon doesn't appear this is my code :

```
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("")
    dialogBuilder.setMessage(list[c])
    dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.cancel)
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", { _, _ ->
        if(c == list.size)
            finish()
    })

    val b = dialogBuilder.create()
    b.show()
}
```

Comment: Just replace `.setIcon(R.drawable.cancel);` to `ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.cancel);`but its deprecated!

Comment: getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cancel) this is deprecated

Comment: @YoLo yes, i edit my post.

Comment: post your error logcat ??

Comment: you need to set title to apply icon to alertdialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Following :

```
  val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    dialogBuilder.setTitle(" ")
    dialogBuilder.setMessage(list[c])
    dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.cancel)
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", { _, _ ->
        if(c == list.size)
            finish()
    })

    val b = dialogBuilder.create()
    b.show()
}
```

Comment: It works but I found that this isn't the icon I need .I need to add image in the dialog at the left

Comment: dialogBuilder.setTitle(" ") I have added space as title